# "No Loop" Constraint for hierarchical data in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, tree, check-constraints

I've got table like this in postgres:

- id primary key
- parent_id foreign key on id
- some data columns

I need no a constrain which prevents cycles on the parent relations. There might be more tree in the table (root of a tree is null in parent_id).

How to achieve this goal?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

You can't express the constraint that an edge-list must be acyclic as a `CHECK` constraint.

It would have to be an `ASSERTION` constraint, which PostgreSQL does not support.

You'll have to `LOCK TABLE` to prevent concurrent `INSERT`s or `UPDATE`s and check it with an `AFTER` trigger.

The resulting lock upgrade issues will result in frequent deadlocks. To prevent them your app will have to lock the table before inserting/updating, e.g.

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE my_table IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
INSERT INTO my_table (...) VALUES (...);
-- Trigger runs to sanity check table here
COMMIT;
```

You might find it useful to make the trigger a deferred constraint trigger, so the table is allowed to temporarily enter invalid states so long as it's valid again by the time you commit.